# Setting up SMTP mail server. Done with installing SMTP. Now what?

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2008, mail-server

I want to host my own mailserver using my own domain. So far I can see that SMTP needs to be installed and the DNS record has to be modified to point to my mailserver. So far so good. But what about mailaccounts? How do I create mail@mydomain.com with username and password so I can start receiving emails in outlook?
What more does it take to be able to receive mails in outlook now that im done with installing SMTP on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing just the smtp service isn't going to get you what you need. In order for users to get their mail you'd need a pop server, or an IMAP server or and exchange server.

What you need is a seperate mail hosting package. Something like Imail from Ipswitch. Or exchange from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP is simply a mail transfer mechanism, it will receive emails for remote SMTP servers and then try an deliver them. It does not handle mailboxes or email accounts, for this you will need a POP3, IMAP or Exchange server.